# Can't see temp table from subquery

Tags: mysql, temporary-tables

I have a query that selects data from tables and one temp table. This works fine, but there is a `GROUP BY`/`ORDER BY` combination that doesn't work well for me. Indeed, I need to order the results and **only then** group by.

So I enclosed the query (without the group by) into a subquery, which is then grouped by the column. This works well in development, however when executed from a procedure, I'm getting the following error: `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'bicou_gtfs_rennes.trip1' doesn't exist`.

The `trip1` table is temporary, all other tables are standard. I'm using InnoDB.

Here's the query that generates this error:
*In this context, `t` is a string containing a table name, and `r2` and `rt` are strings representing a comma separated list of integers (such as `1,34,2,54`).*

```
set @sql = concat("create temporary table t2d as
select * from (
     select
         t1.*
         ,s2d.id as s2d_iid
         ,s2d.stop_name as s2d_name, s2d.stop_lat as s2d_lat, s2d.stop_lon as s2d_lon
         ,st2d.idep as st2d_idep
         ,t2.id as t2_iid, t2.trip_headsign as t2_headsign
         ,t2.trip_type as t2_type
         ,r2.route_short_name as r2_rt, r2.route_long_name as r2_route, r2.route_type as r2_type, r2.route_text_color as r2_text_color, r2.route_color as r2_color

     from trip1 t1
     left join stops s2d on s2d.id = t1.cs1_to
     left join ", st, " st2d on st2d.stop_iid = s2d.id
         and st2d.idep > t1.t1_arr
         and st2d.idep < bicou_gtfs.GtfsTimeAdd(t1.t1_arr, 45*60)
     inner join ", t, " t2 on t2.id = st2d.trip_iid
         and t2.route_iid in (", r2, ")
     inner join routes r2 on r2.id = t2.route_iid and r2.route_type in (", rt, ")

     order by st2d_idep asc
) a group by a.t2_type");

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Below is a very similar query that works, but which doesn't get the right order when grouping:

```
set @sql = concat("create temporary table t2d as
select" -- difference
"    t1.*
     ,s2d.id as s2d_iid
     ,s2d.stop_name as s2d_name, s2d.stop_lat as s2d_lat, s2d.stop_lon as s2d_lon
    ,st2d.idep as st2d_idep
    ,t2.id as t2_iid, t2.trip_headsign as t2_headsign
    ,t2.trip_type as t2_type
    ,r2.route_short_name as r2_rt, r2.route_long_name as r2_route, r2.route_type as r2_type, r2.route_text_color as r2_text_color, r2.route_color as r2_color

from trip1 t1
left join stops s2d on s2d.id = t1.cs1_to
left join ", st, " st2d on st2d.stop_iid = s2d.id
    and st2d.idep > t1.t1_arr 
    and st2d.idep < bicou_gtfs.GtfsTimeAdd(t1.t1_arr, 45*60)
inner join ", t, " t2 on t2.id = st2d.trip_iid
    and t2.route_iid in (", r2, ")
inner join routes r2 on r2.id = t2.route_iid and r2.route_type in (", rt, ")

group by t1_type ", -- difference
"order by st2d_idep asc"); -- difference

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The differences are subtle (I marked the lines), the whole query is enclosed into a `SELECT * FROM (...) a GROUP BY a.t1_type`; and the `GROUP BY t1_type` from the inner query is of course removed.

Is it a normal limitation? My main goal is to order first, then group. If it's possible without enclosing the query in a `SELECT` statement, I'm in.

Here's my setup:

- Debian GNU/Linux 3.2 x86_64
- MySQL 5.6.23
- InnoDB tables

Here's the routine info of the procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.ROUTINES where routine_schema='bicou_gtfs_rennes' and specific_name = 'Get1CJourneys' \G 
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           SPECIFIC_NAME: Get1CJourneys
         ROUTINE_CATALOG: def
          ROUTINE_SCHEMA: bicou_gtfs_rennes
            ROUTINE_NAME: Get1CJourneys
            ROUTINE_TYPE: PROCEDURE
               DATA_TYPE: 
CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH: NULL
  CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH: NULL
       NUMERIC_PRECISION: NULL
           NUMERIC_SCALE: NULL
      DATETIME_PRECISION: NULL
      CHARACTER_SET_NAME: NULL
          COLLATION_NAME: NULL
          DTD_IDENTIFIER: NULL
            ROUTINE_BODY: SQL
      ROUTINE_DEFINITION: begin
*content removed for clarity*
end
           EXTERNAL_NAME: NULL
       EXTERNAL_LANGUAGE: NULL
         PARAMETER_STYLE: SQL
        IS_DETERMINISTIC: NO
         SQL_DATA_ACCESS: CONTAINS SQL
                SQL_PATH: NULL
           SECURITY_TYPE: DEFINER
                 CREATED: 2015-03-15 22:58:20
            LAST_ALTERED: 2015-03-15 22:58:20
                SQL_MODE: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
         ROUTINE_COMMENT: 
                 DEFINER: bicou_gtfs@%
    CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT: utf8
    COLLATION_CONNECTION: utf8_general_ci
      DATABASE_COLLATION: latin1_swedish_ci
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

*Edit March 16th 23:09pm GMT+1*

OK I could narrow it down to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `testbug`()
begin
    drop table if exists t1d;
    drop table if exists t1a;
    drop table if exists trip1;
    drop table if exists t2d;

    create temporary table t1d as
    select t1.id as t1_iid, t1.trip_type as t1_type
    from stops s1d
    left join stop_times_12 st1d on st1d.stop_iid = s1d.id
    inner join trips_part t1 on t1.id = st1d.trip_iid
    limit 10;

    create temporary table t1a as
    select t1.*, st1a.idep as st1a_idep, s1a.id as s1a_iid
    from t1d t1
    left join stop_times_12 st1a on st1a.trip_iid = t1.t1_iid
    left join stops s1a on s1a.id = st1a.stop_iid;

    create temporary table trip1
    select t1.*, cs1.to_stop_iid as cs1_to, GtfsTimeAdd(st1a_idep, cs1.distance) as t1_arr
    from t1a t1
    inner join stop_connections cs1 on cs1.from_stop_iid = t1.s1a_iid
    order by t1_arr asc;

    set @sql = "create temporary table t2d as
    select * from (
        select t1.*
        from trip1 t1
        left join stop_times_12 st2d on st2d.idep < GtfsTimeAdd(t1.t1_arr, 45*60)
    ) a ";

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

More code [available here](https://gist.github.com/BenoitDuffez/c63cacad834ecd2760f8).

The last step fails in this version, but:

- succeeds if I remove the `set @sql ... prepare ... execute` and just execute the query directly (as the others)
- succeeds if I change the `st2d.idep < GtfsTimeAdd(t1.t1_arr, 45*60)` to `st2d.idep < 1000` (random dumb value)
- succeeds if I change the `select * from (...) a` to just the inner `...` query

I'm confused!

*EDIT 2015/09/23*

I was able to reproduce it with very little code. I have uploaded the code as a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/BenoitDuffez/8dc23ed48e995d3e3254).

I have submitted a [MySQL bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78523).

Comment: `SECURITY INVOKER`?  Or `SECURITY DEFINER`?

Comment: Thanks Rick; however I don't know about these. How can I check? My stored procedure doesn't specify anything so it's the server defaults.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM information_schema.ROUTINES` -- or add a WHERE clause to limit to the TABLE_SCHEMA or whatever.

Comment: Please, have a look at the last edit. Is that what you requested?

Comment: `DEFINER` -- does `bicou_gtfs@%` have access to the table in question?  Is `trip1` a table?  or a view?  We may need to see `SHOW CREATE ...` for it.  Or maybe the answer is simply that a `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` cannot be seen by a `PROCEDURE` that is not `SECURITY = INVOKER`

Comment: Yes, `bicou_gtfs@%` has access to all tables. `trip1` is a temporary table. I don't see why `trip1` is generating an error **only** if it is embedded inside a subquery.

Comment: You may need to build a permanent table and reuse it.  (Of course, this would be difficult if multiple threads do the same thing.)

Comment: *"My main goal is to order first, then group."* And there's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess at the answer...

ReCREATE the Stored Procedure with `SECURITY INVOKER` to see if that will let it see the `TEMPORARY` table `trip1`.

(This assumes that you were not doing `SECURITY DEFINER` in order to gain some permissions that the `INVOKER` does not otherwise have.)

Based on the discussion of access to Temporary Tables on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html , I would expect it to be ok (> version 5.6.3).

Comment: I have added `SQL SECURITY INVOKER` before the `begin` statement, the result is the same.

Comment: Nice catch for 5.6.3. However I can't seem to find any information about how to install it, it doesn't look like it's released. I can't be the first to try this query...

Comment: Suggest you write a trivial test case: simple tmp table and simple proc that tries to access the tmp table.  If it fails for that, write a bug a http://bugs.mysql.com .  It may turn out that there is some design reason for disallowing it; if so, they will say so.

Comment: I was exactly doing that :) I didn't have much time to investigate this since yesterday. Thanks for your kind help Rick.

Comment: OK I tried to narrow it down to the minimum in my last edit.

Comment: 5.6.3 was issued 2011-10-03, but it was not a GA version ("Generally Available").  However any version after that will have what it had.